# Check if 2 int arrays contain only unique numbers at the same index

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

If I have 2 `int` arrays a and b and they contain data like this..

```
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 3
a[2] = 7

b[0] = 6
b[1] = 3
b[2] = 5
```

How can I check if all the pairs of numbers are unique e.g. that each combination of `a[i]` and `b[i]` at the same index is not repeated in the rest of the array... So the above data would pass but if I introduced this below it would fail..

```
a[24] = 7
b[24] = 5
```

Because this combination already exists in the array at index 2. Can I do this in LINQ?

Comment: Could you give us more detail of logic? why  `index = 24` will be the expected result?

Comment: What if one array has more elements than the other array? Do you also want to check the uniqueness of the elements of the bigger array that don't have a corresponding element in the smaller array?

Comment: Is the order of the pairs signficant? If b[0] = 1, a[0] = 2 and a[1] = 2, b[1] = 1, does that count as non-unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of the values in the pairs over the two arrays is significant (i.e. `a[0] == 1, b[0] == 2` is considered different from `a[0] == 2, b[0] == 1`) then one way to check for uniqueness using Linq is as follows:

```
bool unique = a.Zip(b).Distinct().Count() == a.Length;
```

If the order of the values in the pairs is NOT significant, it's slightly more fiddly:

```
bool unique = a.Zip(b).DistinctBy(
     x => (Math.Min(x.First, x.Second), Math.Max(x.First,x.Second)))
.Count() == a.Length;
```

These solutions assume that missing values in one of the arrays will be ignored.

(Note: `DistinctBy()` is only available in .Net 6.0 or later, or via a NuGet package.)

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to work this out and solve this with :

```
a.Zip(b, (aPos, bPos) => new { aPosition = aPos, bPosition = bPos }).Distinct().Count()
```

This will tell me how many distinct sets of both values at the same index and so I can work the rest out from here.

Apologies if my question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

try this sample :

```
        int [] aa = a.Distinct().ToArray();
```

or :

```
public static bool HasDuplicates<T>(IList<T> items)
    {
        Dictionary<T, bool> map = new Dictionary<T, bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (map.ContainsKey(items[i]))
            {
                return true; // has duplicates
            }
            map.Add(items[i], true);
        }
        return false; // no duplicates
    }
```

and call :

```
string[] strings = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
Utility.HasDuplicates(strings)// this will return false

int[] items=new []{1,2,3,1};
Utility.HasDuplicates(items)// this will return true
```